# Cannot Connect to Server .NET Core 7

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, connection-string

I'm getting this error while trying to connect to **remote and local** SQL Server

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL  Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Access is denied.)

The same connection string works on the web API 4.6.2 application

The connection string that I'm using the web API app: `"data source=xxx;initial catalog=M3;persist security info=True;user id=xx;password=xx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;Connection Timeout=180;App=EntityFramework&quot;"`

The connection string that I'm using for the core app :
`"Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=M3;Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=True;user id=xx;password=xx;"`

And I have tried multiple other params in my connection but always get this error.
Can the SQL Server version can be not compatible with .NET Core 7?

Comment: This sounds like the host name you've used is incorrect or there's no network path from the host you are using to the host the SQL Server instance is on.

Comment: Initial Catalog is different

Comment: @ThomA what do you mean by network path ?

Comment: That no path, over the network, can be made between the 2 hosts.

Comment: "The same connection string works" but they are NOT the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error)

Comment: No, everything is configured

Comment: I sad that they are the same because I already tried everything.

Comment: Must be firewall then, if you have really validated it not your code or device. Speak to your network administrator.

Comment: and how the webApi app can connect if the firewall is blocking it?

Comment: `provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Access is denied`... smells of a software firewall. Usually they can be configured on a per-process basis, so some programs can connect successfully while others cannot.